# Total variation of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stieltjes-integral

**Setting** We work on a filtered probability space. Let $A$ be a process of finite variation (FV) started from $0$ and $H$ be predictable, positive and such that $H\cdot A$ is defined $\omega$-wise as a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. We denote by $\|A\|$ the total variation process of $A$.

**Question** Does $$\|H\cdot A\|=H \cdot\|A\| \enspace (*)$$ hold? If so, is there a reference with the proof of this result?

**Idea** Let $A=A^{\uparrow}-A^{\downarrow}$ be the Jordan-Hahn decomposition of the FV process $A$ into the difference of two nondecreasing processes started from $0$. Then $\|A\|=A^{\uparrow}+A^{\downarrow}$. Thus $H \cdot\|A\|=H\cdot A^{\uparrow} + H\cdot A^{\downarrow}$ and both integrals in the sum are nondecreasing. Maybe one can now argue with the uniqueness of the Jordan-Hahn decomposition that $H\cdot A^{\uparrow} + H\cdot A^{\downarrow} = \|H\cdot A\|$ holds...

Any help on how to proceed with this idea or any other idea on how to prove $(*)$ are appreciated.

Comment: $\|H\cdot A\|=|H|\cdot \|A\|= H\cdot \|A\|$. Pls refer to
S. W. He et al., *Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus*, Sci. Press and CRC(1992), p.99-102, Ch.3,\S 4.

Comment: @JGWang Thank you for your answer. I looked for this result on p.99-102, but could not find it. Which result are you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(A_t)$ be an adapted (càdlàg) process with finite variation, then $B_t=\int_{[0,t]}|\mathrm{d}A_s|$, the variation process of $A$, is an adapted increasing process(refer to S. W. He et al., *Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus*,
Sci. Press and CRC(1992), p.101, Theorem 3.44). Hence, both
\begin{equation*}
 A^{\uparrow}=\frac12(A+B), \qquad A^{\downarrow}=\frac12(B-A)
\end{equation*}
are adapted increasing processes.
Meanwhile, from the Theorem 5.14-5.15, p.142-143(ibid), there exist optional R-N derivatives $a^+,a^-$ as follows
\begin{gather*}
 a^+=\frac{\mathrm{d}A^{\uparrow}}{\mathrm{d}\|A\|}\ge 0, \quad a^-=\frac{\mathrm{d}A^{\downarrow}}{\mathrm{d}\|A\|}\ge 0,\\
 a^+ + a^-= 1,\qquad a^+ a^-=0,  \qquad \text{a.s. d}\|A\|. \tag{1}
\end{gather*}
From (1) and $0\le a^-, a^+ \le 1$, the Hahn decomposition of $X\triangleq\Omega\times\mathbb{R}_+$(on $(X,\mathscr{O})$) wrt $A$ is
\begin{equation*}
 X=X^+\cup X^-\triangleq\{a^+=1\}\cup \{a^-=1\}.\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Since $H\ge 0$, (2) is the Hahn decomposition of $X\triangleq\Omega\times\mathbb{R}_+$ wrt $H\cdot A$ too, and the Jordan decomposition of $H\cdot A$ is
\begin{equation*}
 (H\cdot A)^+=(a^+ H)\cdot A, \qquad (H\cdot A)^-=(a^- H)\cdot A.
\end{equation*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
 \|H\cdot A\| &= (H\cdot A)^+ + (H\cdot A)^- \\
 & = (a^+ H)\cdot A +(a^- H)\cdot A = H\cdot \|A\|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not yet understand how to use $a^+, a^-$ to prove $(*)$. Could you please elaborate further on your idea?

Comment: Thank you for your question, I add some details in the proof.